# Need to know which legal document to use

Tags: images, legal

Someone wants to buy the rights to an image I created. The buyer is in Europe and I'm in the US. We settled on a price and now I need help determining which legal document I should use.

Are there any good, free legal documents available? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like something to ask a Lawyer

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much just need a 'contract' that you both agree too. In this case, it'd be something specific to the image. It would likely include:

- what the buyer can do with the image license they are purchasing
- what they can not do with the image
- what rights they have with their license
- what rights you reserve as the author
- term (is there a time limit)

Make sure you get a signature.

As usual, "I'm not a lawyer..."